# JQuery 360° Product View with Hotspots

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, 360-degrees

I need a 360 view product script for my HTML website.
But I've just manage to found Flash version of 360 view that I wanted to achieve!
http://www.auris-hybrid.de/index_en.asp#/model

Any JQuery style like this kind of interaction?

I'm using the Jquery Reel to do the 360 view, or is it have others Jquery that can implement with Reel and get the hotspot thing what I wanted?

Comment: I think you can just do something like that with css alone. I mean, it's still just a sequence of carefully shot pictures, nothing magically 3D there. This might help. http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css-coke-can/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind to use some PHP, AJAX-ZOOM even provides a way of defining hotspots with drag & drop in an online editor: http://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example33.php

Answer (score 1):

[Reel](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel) allows you to do this since 1.2 with its [Annotations](https://github.com/pisi/Reel/wiki/Annotations) feature for free. See few [examples (marked with *)](http://test.vostrel.cz/jquery.reel/example/)

You basically can set up hotspots when starting Reel using the `annotations` option. For example this inserts a static HTML link "See door handle close-up" over the image at a place 100 pixels right and 25 pixels down from the upper-left corner:

```
.reel({
    // your Reel options as usual
    annotations: {
        "door_handle": {
            link: {
                text: "See door handle clouse-up",
                href: 'some_your_action_or_link'
            },
            x: 100,
            y: 25
        }
    }
})
```

Please consult the wiki page of [Annotations](https://github.com/pisi/Reel/wiki/Annotations) for how to define dynamic frame-synced annotations and how to style them.