# Web-based image editor to create hotspots

Tags: html, image, html5-canvas

I am working on a webapp which should enable the end-user to add hotspots to an image and link them to some URLs. I've been considering using applets, flash and html5. I would like this web-based editor to work on mobile devices, so I would like to avoid applets and flash.

Any thoughts on the way to go about this?

Comment: There are several ways to solve this using either SVG, canvas or just using DOM elements and CSS. Why not give it a shot - if you get in trouble with your code, update the question with the code and we can take it from there.

Comment: Don't use applets or flash. Start with basic HTML5 and Jquery. Use drag and drop elements and jquery. 

I'm assuming you know some backend stuff, so the jquery and html approach should be pretty easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Ken and Jack. I found a similar discussion on [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306068/jquery-360%C2%B0-product-view-with-hotspots). It seems like jquery reel + droppable plugins are the way to go.